# A random variable is mapping from sample space to real numbers. How about random process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

A random variable is mapping from sample space to real numbers.   How about random process?  Can we think of the simplest random process as again a mapping from sample space to real numbers, with the difference that the sample space now contains ordered pair as the sample points - the first index giving the realizaion number and the second index representing the time index?  Is there any thing wrong with this simple explanation?

Comment: before random processes, looking at a random vectors can be useful

Answer (score 1):

I think of it like this:

A random process is a family of random variables $\{X(t), t \in T\}$ defined on a given probability space, indexed by the parameter $t$ where $t$ varies over an index set $T$.

A random variable is a function defined on the sample space $S$. Thus, a random process $\{X(t), t \in T\}$ is really a function of two arguments $\{X(t, \xi), t \in T, \xi \in S \}$.

For a fixed $t(=t_k)$, $X(t_k, \xi) = X_k(\xi)$ is a random variable denoted by 
$X(t_k)$, as $\xi$ varies over the sample space $S$.

On the other hand, for a fixed sample point $\xi_i \in S$, $X(t, \xi_i) = X_i(t)$ is a single function of time, called a sample function or a realization of the process.

Of course, if both $\xi$ and $t$ are fixed $X(t_k, \xi_i)$ is simply a real number.